# jquery method implementation in vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vue-component

i am buidling up responsive menu bar in vue.js project.

i have the exact method code in the following codepen

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OGvXYY

this has html+css+jquery file.

i have implemented same html , css  format but when it comes to js file i couldnt implement in vue.js , i am bit struggling in it.

i am attaching my vue code, can any help to get working the jquery in vue.js

i have used mounted for the event listener . i have just did some fix in vue,js but this is not correct.

```
  mounted() {
// Register an event listener when the Vue component is ready
window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
},

beforeDestroy() {
// Unregister the event listener before destroying this Vue instance
window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
},

methods: {
  onResize(event) {
  console.log('window has been resized', event);
  function calcWidth() {
    var navwidth = 0;
    var morewidth = document.querySelectorAll('#main 
    .more').outerWidth(true);
    document.querySelectorAll('#main > li:not(.more)').each(function () {
      navwidth += document.querySelectorAll(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    // var availablespace = $('nav').outerWidth(true) - morewidth;
    var availablespace = $('#nav-main').width() - morewidth;
    if (navwidth > availablespace) {
      var lastItem = document.querySelectorAll('#main > 
      li:not(.more)').last();
      lastItem.attr('data-width', lastItem.outerWidth(true));
      lastItem.prependTo(document.querySelectorAll('#main .more ul'));
      calcWidth();
    } else {
      var firstMoreElement = document.querySelectorAll('#main li.more 
        li').first();
      if (navwidth + firstMoreElement.data('width') < availablespace) {
        firstMoreElement.insertBefore(document.querySelectorAll('#main 
      .more'));
      }
    }
    if (document.querySelectorAll('.more li').length > 0) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.more').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('.more').css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
},
```

},

```
  \\orginal js to be convereted to use in vue.js

   $(document).ready(function() {

function calcWidth() {
    var navwidth = 0;
    var morewidth = $('#main .more').outerWidth(true);
    $('#main > li:not(.more)').each(function() {
        navwidth += $(this).outerWidth( true );
    });

    //var availablespace = $('nav').outerWidth(true) - morewidth;
    var availablespace = $('#nav-main').width() - morewidth;

    if (navwidth > availablespace) {
        var lastItem = $('#main > li:not(.more)').last();
        lastItem.attr('data-width', lastItem.outerWidth(true));
        lastItem.prependTo($('#main .more ul'));
        calcWidth();
    } else {

    var firstMoreElement = $('#main li.more li').first();
    if (navwidth + firstMoreElement.data('width') < availablespace) {
        firstMoreElement.insertBefore($('#main .more'));
    }
}

if ($('.more li').length > 0) {
    $('.more').css('display','block');
    } else {
        $('.more').css('display','none');
    }
}

$(window).on('resize load',function(){
    calcWidth();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use same JQuery implementation inside Vue.js by using Wrapper Components.
[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) is a good example of porting existing Select2 Jquery plugin as a Vue Wrapper Component.